# Can't print java string in jsp page using struts2

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, performance

I have a string in a java class in a dynamic web application using struts2. I want to print the string within the jsp page. If I need to resort to using javascript I can.

```
public void class writeToJSP(){
    private String myString = "abcd";
    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }
    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }
}
```

because I'm using struts I've used this line...

> s:property value="myString" />

But it doesn't print at all. Should I use a different method like putting the string in javascript and doing a document.write()?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _doesn't seem to work_. What do you expect and what actually happens? Please synchronize your code and the struts XML element `username` vs `myString`.

Comment: If you can not get the string in the page, how would you get it into JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure. That's why I was asking.

Comment: Should bundle it with the key and print it using text tag instead of hardcode the text which even doesn't compile.

Comment: it was just some dummy text rather than me copying the whole thing